# Hamcrest's anything() doesn't compile

Tags: generics, compiler-errors, hamcrest

Am I missing something here?

```
@Test
public void testAnything(){
    Random random = new Random();
    assertThat(random.nextInt(), is(equalTo(anything())));
}
```

This doesn't compile. Eclipse complains with "The method assertThat(T, Matcher) in the type MatcherAssert is not applicable for the arguments (int, Matcher>)"

Was there something I missed for the use of anything()? I have used other Hamcrest methods in the past... so what is different about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not how `equalTo` works. It calls `Object#equals(Object)` internally and would have to pass `anything()`. That doesn't make sense.  Just omit it and it works:

```
Random random = new Random();
assertThat(random.nextInt(), is(anything()));
```